# General references on dynamics of continuous, piecewise linear interval maps

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

I want to find a general reference on topological and measurable dynamics of continuous piecewise linear interval maps. I am particularly interested in cases with only three pieces. Even characterizing invariant systems with just two pieces would be useful. I know there are literally hundreds of works on specific aspects... but a single, general reference would be great. Thanks.